# data-binding not working on nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When nesting `ng-repeat` it seems that clicking on the toggle button updates that addon in EVERY 'pair' (the first ng-repeat). Can anyone explain to me why this is the case and what I can do to fix it? Check the link above for the custom directive code...

```
<div ng-repeat="pair in pairs track by $index">
    <h3>Pair {{ $index + 1}}</h3>

    <div class='fieldrow'>
    <button ng-repeat="addon in addons track by $index" toggle-button="addon.added">{{addon.name}} (£{{addon.price}})</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is `pair` and what is `addon`, and how are they related. Right now, even though you have a nested `ng-repeat`, you have completely independent data structures, so `addons` array is same for each `pair`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is pair and what is addon, and how are they related. Right now, even though you have a nested ng-repeat, you have completely independent data structures, so addons array is same for each pair. Trott.

Based on this insight, I changed `ng-repeat="addon in addons track by $index"` to `ng-repeat="addon in pair.addons track by $index"`

Problem solved, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your code does not have any problem. see [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IdY79w76zPcyh6hE9638?p=preview) here.
this code is working well:

```
<div ng-repeat="pair in pairs track by $index">
    <h3>Pair {{ $index + 1}}</h3>

    <div class='fieldrow'>
    <button ng-repeat="addon in addons track by $index" toggle-button="addon.added">{{addon.name}} (£{{addon.price}})</button>
    </div>
</div>
```